# Работа с обновлениями Windows

Tags: администрирование, тестирование, обновления, wsus

Хочу узнать у опытных админов, как они следят за новыми обновлениями для клиентских и серверных машин под управлением Windows и тестируют их.

Я более-менее представляю себе, как делать это для клиентских машин (посмотрел логи изменений в новой обнове, поставил на тестовый комп, поработал с юзерским софтом, поковырял день-два, если все в порядке - можно ставить), то вот как поступать с серверами я ума не приложу.

Смущает возможность внезапных конфликтов софта или возможность какой либо софтины вообще отвалиться из-за нового обновления.

Может есть статейка какая полезная, которую я не нашел или может кто поделиться своим опытом?

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Я лично по отключал обновления, стоит windows 7 серв, и windows 2013 server, работают 3 года, пока проблем не было

Comment: Лично я читаю (через rss) https://www.outsidethebox.ms, https://windowsnotes.ru, https://serveradmin.ru/. Это если про винду. Рекомендую покопать там.